# Winform app restart not working when deployed

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to restart my application once an unhandled exception happens.
It's a .NET WinForm app.

```
  [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());

        }
        catch (SystemException ex)
        {
            Log.AddEntry(ex.Message);
        }


    }
    static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.Message);
        Application.Exit();
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.CurrentDirectory+"\\Taskman.exe");
    }
```

I'm throwing an exception intentionally using a button click. When I test the release version on my machine it closes, then restarts normally. But when I deploy it on the production machine, it doesn't.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory` can be anything. If you want the directory where your executable is lcoated, use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

Comment: Are you publishing?  Is Taskman.Exe in the deploy folder?  Check in the project folder on build machine the dates of the release and debug executable and compare to the dates on the deploy machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start the new process before you exit the current one, and make sure that you pass the correct path to the `Process.Start` method:

```
static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.Message);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this:

```
Application.Restart();
```

instead of `Application.Exit();`